# Save XML Data under Root

Tags: c#, xml, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to save multiple entries into an existing xml doc.
But I'm not getting the desired results.

I have the following code:

```
public static void recordScore(ScoreModel scoreModel)
        {
            var path = "../../Media/Leaderboard/Leaderboard.xml";
            var saveModel = new LeaderboardModel();


            Stream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LeaderboardModel));
            if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
            {
                LeaderboardModel o = (LeaderboardModel) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                saveModel.ScoreModels.AddRange(o.ScoreModels);
            }
            fs.Close();

            saveModel.ScoreModels.Add(scoreModel);

            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
                new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(LeaderboardModel));

            System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Open(path, System.IO.FileMode.Append);

            writer.Serialize(file, saveModel);
            file.Close();
        }
```

My output in the xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LeaderboardModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ScoreModels>
    <ScoreModel>
      <Name>Test</Name>
      <GameSpeed>Normal</GameSpeed>
      <Score>11</Score>
    </ScoreModel>
  </ScoreModels>
</LeaderboardModel><?xml version="1.0"?>
<LeaderboardModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ScoreModels>
    <ScoreModel>
      <Name>Test</Name>
      <GameSpeed>Normal</GameSpeed>
      <Score>11</Score>
    </ScoreModel>
  </ScoreModels>
</LeaderboardModel><?xml version="1.0"?>
<LeaderboardModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ScoreModels>
    <ScoreModel>
      <Name>Test</Name>
      <GameSpeed>Normal</GameSpeed>
      <Score>11</Score>
    </ScoreModel>
  </ScoreModels>
</LeaderboardModel><?xml version="1.0"?>
```

As you can see it's outputting the LeaderboardModel and ScoreModels every time.
It's only supposed to write that once and then add the new ScoreModel under that Root.

EDIT:
My expected result:

```
    <LeaderboardModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <ScoreModels>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <GameSpeed>Normal</GameSpeed>
        <Score>1</Score>
      </ScoreModels>
      <ScoreModels>
        <Name>Test2</Name>
        <GameSpeed>Normal</GameSpeed>
        <Score>2</Score>
      </ScoreModels>
      <ScoreModels>
        <Name>Test3</Name>
        <GameSpeed>Normal</GameSpeed>
        <Score>3</Score>
      </ScoreModels>
    </LeaderboardModel>
```

Also how would I read it back again from this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LeaderboardModel lm = new LeaderboardModel();
        List<LeaderboardModelScoreModels> m = new List<LeaderboardModelScoreModels>();
        lm.ScoreModels = m;

        for (int i= 0;i < 2;i++)
        {
            m.Add(new LeaderboardModelScoreModels() { ScoreModel = new LeaderboardModelScoreModelsScoreModel() { GameSpeed = "hi", Name = "hi", Score = 1 } });
        }
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(LeaderboardModel));

        System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Open("D:\\a.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Append);

        writer.Serialize(file, lm);
        file.Close();

    }
```

MOdel :

```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
  [System.SerializableAttribute()]
 [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
 [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = 
 false)]
 public partial class LeaderboardModel
 {

private List<LeaderboardModelScoreModels> scoreModelsField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ScoreModels")]
public List<LeaderboardModelScoreModels> ScoreModels
{
    get
    {
        return this.scoreModelsField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.scoreModelsField = value;
    }
}
}


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
 public partial class LeaderboardModelScoreModels
{

private LeaderboardModelScoreModelsScoreModel scoreModelField;

/// <remarks/>
public LeaderboardModelScoreModelsScoreModel ScoreModel
{
    get
    {
        return this.scoreModelField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.scoreModelField = value;
    }
}
}


 [System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class LeaderboardModelScoreModelsScoreModel
{

private string nameField;

private string gameSpeedField;

private byte scoreField;

/// <remarks/>
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        return this.nameField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.nameField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public string GameSpeed
{
    get
    {
        return this.gameSpeedField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.gameSpeedField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
public byte Score
{
    get
    {
        return this.scoreField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.scoreField = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm still getting the same result...
I will update my description with what it's supposed to look like.

Comment: https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ use this and let me know if you getting a valid XML .I am getting invalid XML .

Comment: It's currently generating an invalid document.
But my expected outcome is valid.

Comment: Then your expected outcome should Parse without error .If you have XSD then you can edit your description or else you need to verify first that outcome gets parsed well.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I'm still getting the wrong output. It's repeating Leaderboard the whole time instead of adding ScoreModels into the existing Leaderboard...

Comment: Using the Model that I put in my answer I am getting valid XML as shown here http://collabedit.com/22qjv which is exactly you wanted .

Comment: I managed to get it working. I had my serialize at the wrong attribute. ID10T mistake. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Most of the time People make error while creating the model.In Visual Studio you have Paste Special Option (Create Class File ->Edit Tab-> Paste Special and Choose either Json or XML).Then there is low chance that you will end up with an error.